# AWS Cloud9 Stuck Connecting

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloud9

My AWS Cloud9 instance is stuck connecting since yesterday. It gives the error:

"This is taking longer than expected. The delay may be caused by high CPU usage in your environment, or your T2 or T3 instance is running out of burstable CPU capacity credits, or there are VPC configuration issues"

I have tried changing the instance type to a larger one. I have tried rebooting as well.

It started happening after I put an ENV variable that was super long into the .bashrc file.

I would greatly appreciate any thoughts on how I can fix this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The change you made in your ENV variable is affecting the VPC configuration you have created and so you get this stuck connecting to your VPC.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah, That is what I figured as well. Do you know of any way to fix it?

Comment: Unfortunately I can't access the environment, so I can't be sure of what it was exactly. I do know it was a JSON string probably 40k characters or so long.